# CGI Script that prints out an incoming param

Tags: apache2, python, cgi

I am trying to write out a python cgi script that will redirect me to a page that prints out one of the incoming params.

The rewrite rule looks like this: RewriteRule `^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/redirect.py?url=%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L,QSA,PT].`

Basically all I want to do is print out the param url between `<h1></h1>` tags. I have never written a cgi script before so any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "[L,QSA,PT]" does, but I would do something like `^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/redirect.py`

redirect.py should look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print """Content-type: text/html

<html><head><title>Redirect</title></head><body>
<h1>%s/%s</h1></body></html>"""%(os.environ['HTTP_HOST'], os.environ['REQUEST_URI'])
```

I haven't tested it so I might be totally wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are [lots of resources on the internet](http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/doc/0.5.3/html_multipage/web/node21.html) for `Hello World`-type programs. Or you could go with the [standard documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) for the answer.